# Smooth horizontal and vertical scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, smooth-scrolling

I have started a website in which I need smooth horizontal and vertical scrolling. A menu on the right, so I can click the links to the different sections. I found some pretty useful codes and explanations of how to do it vertically. But I've been wondering, how could I do it horizontally **without** the use of plugins such as [Fullpage.js](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/)?

Comment: Why wouldn't you want to use fullPage.js? Rather than reinventing the wheel, the benefits of using a plugin like it are quite important when you start considering things such as touch screen devices, touch laptops, animations performance, cross browser compatibility, old browsers compatibility, callbacks, infinite scrolling, keyboard accessibility, responsiveness etc.

Comment: I don't want to use external resources.

Comment: Yeah... I think the same....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of how you can do horizontal smooth scrolling to the right when you click a button by using animate() method. Hope this can be useful.

```
    $(".downArrow").click(function () {
        var topPos = $('body').scrollTop();
        $("body").animate({
            scrollTop: topPos + 800
        }, 800);
    });
```

Comment: What would I write in the html? `divs`? how would I set them? would I move them with `margin-left: -100vw`?

Comment: Here is the full example.  [link](https://jsfiddle.net/j6za34r3/2/) .Here you can do smooth vertical scrolling by clicking the arrows. If you wanna do the same but triggered with the scrollbar just change the event and use onScroll (Here the doc: [link](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onscroll.asp) )

Comment: Youe example doesn't seem to work, I'm using firefox 30 and ie 11

Comment: I mistaken vertical and horizontal. Here the vertical example [link](https://jsfiddle.net/j6za34r3/13/)

Comment: Just to point it out. This method won't be as "smooth" as fullPage.js. And quite notably in old computers and mobile phones. fullPage.js is using CSS3 for its animations while you are making use of javascript, which performs much slower.